# Injecting a JBoss Quartz Scheduler into Spring

Tags: spring, jboss, quartz-scheduler

- Spring 3.0.6
- Quartz 1.8.5
- JBoss 5.1

I am trying to inject a Scheduler provided through JNDI by JBoss into my spring configuration.  It is not obvious to me how or where I inject the JNDI name.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<bean id="task" class="com.hamacher.quartz.MessagePrinterTaskPOJO">
    <constructor-arg name="message" value="Clark Griswold"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="task" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="print" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
<property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```